# JList disappears when added to JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlist

I don't know why this is happening, I've looked up nearly every Stack Overflow question regarding this.
The error is, When I add a `JScrollPane` to `JList`, Nothing shows up. Even if I'm adding it to the frame.

```java
JList mainlist = new JList();
JScrollPane listScroller = new JScrollPane(mainlist);
listScroller.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
listScroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

mainlist.setToolTipText("List of People");
mainlist.setFont(new Font("Consolas", Font.BOLD, 13));
int pos = mainlist.getModel().getSize();
DefaultListCellRenderer renderer =  (DefaultListCellRenderer)mainlist.getCellRenderer();  
renderer.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);  
mainlist.setModel(model);
mainlist.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
mainlist.setBackground(new Color(44, 47, 51));
mainlist.setBounds(10, 108, 780, 248);
mainlist.setFixedCellHeight(20);
mainlist.setFixedCellWidth(30);
mainlist.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10,10, 10, 10)); 
frm.getContentPane().add(listScroller);
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) `mainlist.setBounds(10, 108, 780, 248)` Don't do that, it especially breaks scroll panes. :- Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should apply bounds to your scrollPane and not Your List

```
listScroller.setBounds(10, 108, 780, 248);
```

Also make sure Your Content Pane has `null` layout for `setBounds()` to work or better just use an border layout and set the `preferred&maximum Size()` to what works for you

Comment: I tried experimenting that and It worked, Was just about to update my question and saw you answer the same thing! Setting bounds for ScrollPane worked.